# Cannot apply indexing to an expression of type 'T'

Tags: c#

I've create a generic method like

```
public void BindRecordSet<T>(IEnumerable<T> coll1, string propertyName)
            where T : class
```

and in my class 'T' i've write indexer

```
public object this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            Type t = typeof(SecUserFTSResult);
            PropertyInfo pi = t.GetProperty(propertyName);
            return pi.GetValue(this, null);
        }
        set
        {
            Type t = typeof(SecUserFTSResult);
            PropertyInfo pi = t.GetProperty(propertyName);
            pi.SetValue(this, value, null);
        }
    }
```

now in my method when i write code like

`var result = ((T[])(coll1.Result))[0];`

`string result= secFTSResult[propertyName];`

I am getting the error
Cannot apply indexing to an expression of type 'T'

Please help
Thanks

Comment: Hi BoltClock, BindRecordSet<T> method is generic type method and here T is BindRecordSet<Student> where Student is a class

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless you use a generic constraint to an interface which declares the indexer, then indeed - that won't exist for *abitrary* `T`. Consider adding:

```
public interface IHasBasicIndexer { object this[string propertyName] {get;set;} }
```

and:

```
public void BindRecordSet<T>(IEnumerable<T> coll1, string propertyName)
        where T : class, IHasBasicIndexer
```

and:

```
public class MyClass : IHasBasicIndexer { ... }
```

(feel free to rename `IHasBasicIndexer` to something more sensible)

Or a simpler alternative in 4.0 (but a bit hacky IMO):

```
dynamic secFTSResult = ((T[])(coll1.Result))[0];    
string result= secFTSResult[propertyName];
```

(which will resolve it once per `T` at runtime)

Comment: I'd prefer `interface IIndexable<T> { this[T index] { get; set; } }` to match BCL style. I'm surprised it doesn't exist already....

Comment: @Simon the interface as described takes `string` and returns `object` - where is the `T` in that?

Comment: @MSingh - I missed an `object` in the answer; see the update (to the interface definition)

Comment: Use as `where T : class, IIndexable<string>`.

Comment: @Simon meh... using generic based on a sample of 1 is overkill IMO. It isn't "generic" if it has a single use-case.

Comment: Hence my justification of "to match BCL style". Being able to see `IIndexable<string>` and know exactly what it is without looking it up is useful. But whatever, it's just style, I'm not commenting further :)